# Set default shipping method as table rate and not free shipping

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods, table-rates

I have two shipping method`s first is free shipping and second is table rate. I want to set the default shipping method as table rate and not as free shipping. how can we set it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You means default  table rate is selected out of both shipping?

Comment: Yes, I want table rate as selected out of both the shipping method!

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the free shipping method and enabled only the flat shipping method. so that you can only flat shipping method in the checkout page while placing an order.

[image: enable flat shipping method]

disable free shipping method

[image: disable free shipping method]

frontend side

[image: frontend checkout page]

Answer (score 0):

There are several free extensions that allow you to do this. Try this one: [Default Shipping & Payment method [M2]](https://www.hungersoft.com/p/magento2-default-shipping-payment). It will let you set any shipping/payment method you want as default.